# Timeout when connecting RDS using AWS session manager via EC2 instance

Tags: iptables, aws, amazon-ec2

I am having trouble accessing AWS RDS instance in a private subnet using session manager through ec2 instance (Ubuntu).

Port forwarding using AWS Session manager -

```bsh
    aws ssm start-session --target $INSTANCE_ID \
                       --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession \
                       --parameters '{"portNumber":[3307],"localPortNumber":["8000"]}' \
                                             --profile=production \
                       --region=us-east-1`
```

Now local port 8000 successfully forwarded to port 3307 of EC2.

`lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN`

`session-manager 59744 xrage   12u     IPv4 0xa6c821d0a800e9a1         0t0                 TCP 127.0.0.1:8000 (LISTEN)`

EC2 instance has an iptable rule that forward all traffic on port 3307 to rds host at port 3306 (MYSQL PORT).

```bsh
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3307 -j DNAT  --to-destination <rds_private_ip>:3306
```

This allowed me to access remote host on the desired port from ec2, But still, the remote host is not accessible locally on port 8000.

Network details on the local machine -

- Not using any proxy
- Firewall disabled on mac

So it's clear that SSM setup is working but something else is blocking this traffic, Need some help here.

Answer (score 0):

When you said that remote host can access MySQL instance, u tried that port (telnet) or mysql command line client, just to confirm?

Assuming yes to the above, I would move on to the next step. It is my understanding that AWS-StartPortForwardingSession is to cover this scenario: You have something running on your EC2, say MySQL db that you hand rolled and installed. You want to forward traffic from your workstation (for example) to the MySQL instance running on EC2, via SSM. That's what AWS-StartPortForwardingSession was designed for.

In your case, the EC2 is more of a bastion host, and your MySQL instance is RDS type. So your EC2 does not host anything -- it simply is a gateway to connect to your RDS.

Assuming the above assumption is correct, I would use AWS-StartSSHSession instead (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-enable-ssh-connections.html).

The full answer would be verbose, but I just did it a few months ago: https://medium.com/@clearwaterstream/recipe-connect-to-an-rds-database-in-a-private-subnet-from-your-workstation-over-https-c66db6ead9f0

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct and my ec2 instance is working as bastion host only. And yes It worked with AWSStartSSH session, but ssh data will be encrypted and can not be logged for auditing that's why I was trying this approach.

Comment: I am still curious why this solution is not working.

Comment: @xrage Just a thought: The fact there is encryption in-place and that you cannot "snort" the traffic is a good thing, in my opinion. I think auditing (which commands were executed, session info and user info, etc) should be logged at the DB level, not at transport level. This way you can connect whichever way to the DB and have audit logging in place ...

Answer (score 0):

On May 27, 2022, AWS [announced support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/05/aws-systems-manager-support-port-forwarding-remote-hosts-using-session-manager/) for **Port Forwarding to Remote Hosts using Session Manager**:

> To get started, install SSM Agent version 3.1.1374.0 or later on the managed instances that you are establishing a port forwarding session with.
> You can start a port forwarding session from the command line using the
> `AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost` Session Manager document.

To start a port forwarding session, run the following command from the CLI. Replace the values of `<EC2_INSTANCE_ID>`, `<RDS_DB>`, `<RDS_PORT>`, and `<LOCAL_PORT>` with your information:

```bash
aws ssm start-session \
    --target <EC2_INSTANCE_ID> \
    --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
    --parameters '{"host":["<RDS_DB>"], "portNumber":["<RDS_PORT>"], "localPortNumber":["<LOCAL_PORT>"]}'
```

More details are available in AWS Documentation: [AWS Systems Manager - User Guide - Session Manager - Starting a Session (Port Forwarding to Remote Host)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#sessions-remote-port-forwarding).

Related AWS Blog Posts:

- [Use port forwarding in AWS Systems Manager Session Manager to connect to remote hosts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/use-port-forwarding-in-aws-systems-manager-session-manager-to-connect-to-remote-hosts/)
- [Securely connect to an Amazon RDS or Amazon EC2 database instance remotely with your preferred GUI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securely-connect-to-an-amazon-rds-or-amazon-ec2-database-instance-remotely-with-your-preferred-gui/)

Related GitHub Issues and Pull Requests:

- [aws/amazon-ssm-agent - Issue #208 - Feature request: Forward to remote port](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/208)
- [aws/amazon-ssm-agent - Issue #240 - Feature request: Allow specifying IP for AWS-StartSSHSession #240](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/240)
- [aws/amazon-ssm-agent - Pull Request #389 - Support for specifying a host for port forwarding](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/pull/389)

Related StackOverflow Question:

- [AWS cli - setup multiple connections in one shell script to connect to RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74216375/aws-cli-setup-multiple-connections-in-one-shell-script-to-connect-to-rds)